# get values of a function returning ArrayList<String[]>

Tags: java

I have function returning an `ArrayList<String[]>`.
How can I get values from this returning `ArrayList<String[]>`?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of using a "for-each loop" to iterate through String elements in an ArrayList.

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...
    // For every item in the list
    for(String value: list) {
        // print the value
        System.out.println(value);
    }
```

What is a "for-each" loop?
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Also remember you can randomly access values in the ArrayList using the index.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("0");
list.add("1");

int index = 1;
list.get(index); // You get the value 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(object o in arrayList)
{
// cast to appropriate type
// eg string s = o as string;
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();

for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
    String[] stringArray = list.get(i);

    for(String s : stringArray) {
       System.out.println(s);
    }

    or 

    for(int j=0; j<stringArray.length; j++) {
       System.out.println(stringArray[j]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//If just print out
ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
...
for(String[] item : list) {
    //Use Arrays.toString
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(item));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each list entry is either an array of Strings or `null`.

If you're interested in the `String[]` objects, then I suggest using the enhanced for loop:

```
ArrayList<String[]> result = myMethodProvidingTheList();
for(String[] strings : result) {
  if (strings != null {
    doSomethingWith(strings);
  }
}
```

If you need the values from the arrays now, use the same enhanced for loop for the array:

```
private void doSomethingWith(String[] strings) {
  for (String string : strings) {
    if (string != null) {
       doSomethingWith(string);
    }
  }
}
```